# Javascript return prompt onclick

Tags: javascript, php, prompt

I want to check for empty prompt and null both in same command.

These 2 work on its own:

- first checks for empty string (although maybe not tab necessarily?)
- second checks for null (cancel)

I dont know how to combine them in single line?

```
<a href="#" onclick="return prompt('Enter title for new player:') != ''">Duplicate</a>

<a href="#" onclick="return prompt('Enter title for new player:') != null">Duplicate</a>
```

---

EDIT: (my example is little more complicated)

I use php for translation:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" onclick="return prompt('<?php printf(esc_attr__('Enter title for new player:', 'domain'))?>') || false"<?php _e('Duplicate', 'domain'); ?></a>
```

I need to get title of successful prompt (so I can send it with GET)

I tried:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var btn = $(this), val = btn.val();

    if(val !== null || val != ''){
        console.log(val)
    }
});
```

but it returns empty string always.

Comment: Make a function and call it?

Comment: Null coalesce: `return prompt('Enter title for new player:') || false`

Comment: Can you make it re-prompt if they click ok on empty input? because now if you click ok on empty field user expects something but we dont have action.

Comment: @Toniq, I've supplied an answer for the re-prompt. Does that do what you asked?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to continue only when you have an input supplied, and re-prompt if no value supplied, then call the prompt again depending on the result.

```
<a href="#" onclick="getName()">Enter title</a>

<script>
    function getName() {
        var name = prompt('Enter name for new player:');

        if(name == null || name == "") {
            getName();
        }

        return name;
    }
</script>
```